# How to convert datashader canvas.points to GeoTiff?

Tags: heatmap, scatter, holoviews, datashader, pyviz

I am interested on generating GeoTiff images given a set of scattered points, the dataset is normally between 500K points up to 2M points. I have been using datashader and geoviews to generate static images of the data and that works fine. However, when I want to generate the geotiff, there are two options:

- To generate an RGB geotiff with the coloring as provided by datashader Image color map
- To use the values inside the geotiff to create a colormap on the geotiff server.

We are interested on going for the second solution but I do not understand the values which I extract from the shade function:

```
import pandas as pd
import datashader as ds
import datashader.transfer_functions as tf
df = pd.DataFrame({"x": [0, 0.6, 1, 1.2, 2, 5], "y":[0, 0.6, 0.8, 1, 5, 6], "value":[1, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 0.5]})
canvas = ds.Canvas(plot_width=100, plot_height=100, x_range=(0, 5), y_range=(0, 5), x_axis_type="linear", y_axis_type="linear")
shaded = tf.shade(canvas.points(df, "x", "y", ds.mean("value")))
```

As far as I know, I extract the aggregated values from shade as numpy and can use this array to save a GeoTiff with one band but the values into that array make no sense for me.

```
shaded.to_numpy().max()
4293318829
```

It is always huge numbers which have no relationship with the aggregation process.

So the questions are, what do those values actually mean?
Is it possible to get the actual aggregated values ?
Is it possible to extract the color mapping from an Image object so I can pass it to the server and they color the geotiff as I expect it to be colored?

Answer (score 0):

So datashader uses a couple of steps to produce the results we get. The more important, there is a step in which the values are mapped to RGB using the color_map input. After that the colourize function inside datashader stack the 4 RGBA uint8 arrays of size (100, 100) into one uint32 (100, 100) array using this:

From datashader:

```
/transfer_functions/__init__.py

values = module.dstack([r, g, b, a]).view(module.uint32).reshape(a.shape)
```

That is why the values are so strange. To get the RGBA, one can access the data like this:

```
shaded.to_numpy().base.shape
(310, 400, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

All your questions can be found in the [datashader documentation](https://datashader.org/getting_started/Pipeline.html#pipeline).
The actual aggregated values are stored in `canvas.points(df, "x", "y", ds.mean("value"))`. This is a xarray object. You can write it to netcdf or geotiff easily. But in this way you will lose the geographic references/coordinate system information.

I suppose your dataset use [epsg:3857](https://epsg.io/3857) as your projection coordinate system.  You can use the `rioxarray` package to add the geographic references/coordinate system information and write to geotiff (see https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/latest/rioxarray.html#rioxarray.rioxarray.XRasterBase.write_crs). like this:

```py
ag = canvas.points(df, "x", "y", ds.mean("value"))
ag.rio.write_crs("epsg:3857", inplace=True)
ag.rio.to_raster("../data/interim/test2.tif")
```

I think the color mapping should be the function of your server. To know what information can geotiff store, you can check here:https://www.bluemarblegeo.com/about-geotiff-format/.